# Open a different iframe Fancybox when one is closed

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have 2 distinctly different iframe Fancyboxes (2.1.5) that are used as quizes on a site - the first one:

```
$('.fancybox1').fancybox({
                width: 800,
                height: 500,
                fitToView: false,
                autoSize: false,
                beforeClose: function () {
                                var Q1 = $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find('input#Q1').val();
                                $('#Q1').attr('value', Q1 );
                            //(and a lot more)
                }    
                });
```

and the second:

```
$('.fancybox2').fancybox({
                width: 800,
                height: 500,
                fitToView: false,
                autoSize: false,
                beforeClose: function () {
                            //some other functions, data collection etc
                            //(and a lot more)
                }    
                });
```

Basically all I want to do is open the second one when the first one is closed - How would i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `afterClose` callback to the first and *trigger* a `click` *event* to the second *selector* from there like

```
afterClose: function () {
    $('.fancybox2').trigger("click");
}
```

[image]